# AWS eb create - unable to find role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have RoR application, and when using AWS eb command line I try to create ElasticBeanstalk application, it asks me for --service-role flag

I give him IAM role that exists: for example admin with admin permissions or aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

so I write `eb create --service-role aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`

It starts to deploy, but after a while it transition health to warning because of:
`Unable to assume role "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role". Verify that the role exists and is configured correctly.`

Thats why my deployment fails.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an environment you assign a service role to it. You need to create this role first. There are predefined ones you can use. Through the console you can create this role as you create your environment.

These resources should help you:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html

Comment: In my case the role exists but the same warning is raised by AWS on deployments, because the role is missing the necessary trust relationships. [Based on the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html#concepts-roles-service) I had to update the existing role to make the warning disappear.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert Care to share your fix? I've read the documentation and copy-pasted into the role's trust relationship but am still getting the same error.

Comment: @lionello Right now I don't have access to AWS. You have to find the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` in AWS, click on it, find the Trust relations (or similar) tab on the bottom part of the page and edit the trust relations. You have to stick [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/jneCMsh6) (taken from the manual) into the array of elements in the actual JSON. Hope this helps. But the docs says it all. Just be really thorough reading it, and in going through your role's permissions. If you have permission. Delete the role, and recreate it by doing a demo deploy. Hope this helps. Happy Holidays man!