# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Environment Fails to Launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have created a few environments before so I know how the Amazon EBS works however lately I have been having the following issue while creating an environment:

*The instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role associated with the environment has no role. Please attach a role to the instance profile.*

I follow the steps to create a new environment. When it gets to the **Permissions** page, I create a new role as there are no existing ones. Then I follow the rest of the steps and eventually it starts to launch. After a couple minutes, I get the error above. Any help towards this will be helpful.

Comment: Earlier Elastic Beanstalk used to create a default EC2 instance profile named aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role the first time an AWS account created an environment. However, recent AWS security guidelines don’t allow an AWS service to automatically create roles with trust policies to other AWS services, EC2 in this case. Please check this detailed answer to fix the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605

Answer (score 9):

To solve this issue, I created a new role from the IAM Manager console. I selected Amazon EC2 as my Service Role Type. I attached the AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess policy. Then when creating a new environment, I chose the new role I created.

Comment: you're welcome. I figured that I couldn't be the only one having this issue!

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but when using eb create, how do you chose the role when creating an environment? Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating a new environment via Elastic Beanstalk or via EC2

Answer (score 2):

Though I am bit late in answering this issue, posting here if someone faces this error now.

In case your user has all the required permission to create role and BS has already created the "The instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role".

The reason of this error is due to roles only and when we try to launch EC2 from aws BS, it creates a role naming "**aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role**" with required permissions.

But, if there is already a role with Trusted entities "AWS service: ec2" so BS will check permission in that already existing older role.

So go to Roles > Search ec2 related roles and select the role which is active.

And just add **AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess** permission to that ec2 role, and  this issue will be resolved.