# Elastic Beanstalk instance profile not automatically created when using Terraform in eu-west-2 region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, amazon-iam

I am using Terraform to successfully spin up some Elastic Beanstalk apps (Single Docker configuration) and enable auto-scaling as part of the app / environment creation.

This works fine in most regions I’ve tried, but when I try to spin it up in London (eu-west-2) I get an error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.my-service-env: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.my-service-env: Error waiting for Elastic Beanstalk Environment (e-mt7f3i5bmq) to become ready: 2 error(s) occurred:

* 2018-06-11 19:31:29.28 +0000 UTC (e-mt7f3i5bmq) : Environment must have instance profile associated with it.
* 2018-06-11 19:31:29.39 +0000 UTC (e-mt7f3i5bmq) : Failed to launch environment.
```

I have found that if I manually attach the aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role as the IamInstanceProfile it works fine - but this relies on the role having been automatically created previously...

Is there something about the eu-west-2 region which would mean the Beanstalk apps don’t get created with the instance profile as they do in other regions?

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer might be helpful:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605

Answer (score 13):

For others stuck on this issue I have found a solution by adding the instance profile directly as a setting. This instance profile doesn't get automatically added like it does when creating an elastic beanstalk through the console. Below is the full beanstalk environment resource defined:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalkenvironment" {
  name                = "dev-example"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.beanstalkapp.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.14.1 running Docker 18.09.9-ce"
  version_label       = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.beanstalkapplicationversion.name
  setting {
      namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
      name = "IamInstanceProfile"
      value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "InstanceType"
    value = "t2.micro"
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "test"
    Environment = "test"
  }
}
```

The exact setting used to fix this error was:

```
setting {
      namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
      name = "IamInstanceProfile"
      value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }
```

To find what the value "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role" that's required I checked an existing elastic beanstalk instance that was created through the console. Under the environment, in configuration there is a security section. The role name needed is listed as "IAM instance profile". Hopefully this helps others who get stuck on this issue.

Comment: the posted problem is that the role is not created by default, only if you do the first ever eb from cli or aws console according to aws docs: "When you launch an environment using the Elastic Beanstalk console or the EB CLI, Elastic Beanstalk creates a default instance profile, called aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role, and assigns managed policies with default permissions to it."

Comment: @seekingtheoptimal, this is no more true, earlier Elastic Beanstalk used to create a default EC2 instance profile named `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` the first time an AWS account create an environment. However, recent AWS security guidelines don’t allow an AWS service to automatically create roles with trust policies to other AWS services, EC2 in this case. Please check the detailed answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605

Comment: thanks for the update @ArpitJain - aws is getting more and more like somebody once put it: like death by a thousand papercuts : )