# Terraform - The instance profile associated with the environment does not exist

Tags: terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create an Elastic Beanstalk application but I am coming across the error:

**The instance profile iam_for_beanstalk associated with the environment does not exist.**

The role does exist as you can see here:

[image]

and it is being created via Terraform through the following code:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "beanstalk" {
  name = "iam_for_beanstalk"
  assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/assumerole.json")
}
```

assumerole.json looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {
          "StringEquals": {
            "sts:ExternalId": "elasticbeanstalk"
          }
        }
    }]
}
```

And here is how I try to associate it to the newly created application:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "nodejs" {
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.nodejs.name
  name = "stackoverflow"
  version_label = var.app_version
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.4.6 running Node.js 14"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value     = "iam_for_beanstalk"
  }...
```

I also tried to assign the name like below, but no success:

```
value     = aws_iam_role.beanstalk.name
```

Comment: Earlier Elastic Beanstalk used to create a default EC2 instance profile named aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role the first time an AWS account created an environment. However, recent AWS security guidelines don’t allow an AWS service to automatically create roles with trust policies to other AWS services, EC2 in this case. Please check this detailed answer to fix the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to create an `aws_iam_instance_profile` resource:

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "beanstalk_instance_profile" {
  name = "stack-overflow-example"
  role = aws_iam_role.beanstalk.name
}
```