# Elastic Beanstalk says 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role' does not exist when creating environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting this error when trying to create an `Elastic Beanstalk` environment:

> "the instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role associated with
> the environment does not exist."

I am just trying to create a simple web space with `PHP` and `MySQL` and I choose all the default settings when setting up the environment.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: I got it working by creating the role myself in IAM, following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72682542/327528

Comment: Earlier Elastic Beanstalk used to create a default EC2 instance profile named aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role the first time an AWS account created an environment. However, recent AWS security guidelines don’t allow an AWS service to automatically create roles with trust policies to other AWS services, EC2 in this case. Please check this detailed answer to fix the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605

Answer (score 6):

When creating an environment in eb, you need two roles (service and instance profile role). Apparently the instance profile role is not being created automatically. So you need to go to IAM and create a role called aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role with the following policies: AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier and AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html

Comment: How do I know >>exactly<< what policies do I set where?

Comment: @Michal, please check this detail answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605

Comment: Thanks you so much, but wow, that's insane. I've been creating eb applications every year on new accounts and I'm astounded. EB lets you create the service role automatically, and it lets you skip the instance profile role. Why doesn't it at least warn you it's not going to work without one...

Answer (score 2):

Due to the security policies of AWS, Elastic Beanstalk does not create instance profile role automatically now for new accounts. You need to manually create an instance profile and add the managed policies of AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier in it.