# Errors in environments events AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I tried to run a sample app with Elastic Beanstalk based on Docker, unfortunately my environment doesn't work. I defined an *aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role* during the creation process, but in the environment events after initialization, I see the error `The instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role associated with the environment does not exist` I chose all settings through the AWS GUI. Rule exist in my IAM service. Do you have any clues as to why it's not working?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138569/elastic-beanstalk-says-aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role-does-not-exist-when-creat

Comment: Please check this detail answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605