# Unable to Deploy Sample Node.js Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

## Unable to Deploy Sample Node.js Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Despite Correct IAM Role Attachments

I am attempting to deploy a sample Node.js application ( Web server environment ) to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Generally, I understand that a sample application should run without any issues. However, in my case, I am encountering a problem.

Initially, I let Elastic Beanstalk create a new role during the environment creation process. When this did not work, I manually attached additional policies to the role in an attempt to resolve the issue.

The IAM role currently has the following policies attached:

- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
- AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy

Unfortunately, even after these changes, I still cannot successfully deploy the sample application.

Are there additional steps required to get the sample Node.js application running in Elastic Beanstalk? Could there be another issue I am overlooking related to the role configuration or permissions? Are there limits I may have exceeded? Or could this possibly be a service issue on AWS's end?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

### Permissions

[image]

Permission Now
[image]

### Trust relationship

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust Relationship (Now)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com",
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the role policies and trust relationship policy attached to the role?

Comment: what do you see in trust relationship tab?

Comment: @ArpitJain Here is the Trust relationship

Comment: Can you try adding `AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier` policy also and launch the environment?

Comment: @ArpitJain I did, but unfortunately, i had the same error. I also changed Trust relationship aa little bit.

Comment: I misread before, in trust policy, you should only have `ec2.amazonaws.com` as Service.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same error. Started trying yesterday, i have done this on other occasions without problem, would be nice to know what have changed

Comment: @BastianE. may be this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605) would help you.

Comment: It was a weird problem, AWS wasn't recognizing the role with the name "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role". I had to create a different one with same specifications but different name. Check my answer below for details. 
Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. You have to create a different role with a name different than "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role".

Attach the following policies:[image: Policies for role]

Specify the following Trust Relationship:
[image: Trust relationship]

Then when creating the EB env, select it in the following box:
[image]

It should go as expected.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually don't see anything on EC2 instance profile drop menu. Did you need to create ec2 instance and attach role by **yourself**? If so how did you do on web console? [This video](https://youtu.be/EVmbnmae3vg?t=182) seems to do something similar, but console UI is not the same anymore and I cannot find `Attach/Replace IAM role`

Comment: after I created IAM role from IAM console, I was able to see option on EC2 instance profile, thank you for your answer!