Role created to use as EC2 Instance Profile for Elastic Beanstalk not visible
I'm trying to create my first Elastic Beanstalk environment in a fresh AWS account (not my first EB, I've spun up like a 100 of these things).
In the old days, the Elastic Beanstalk wizard used to create the role (wrapped in an EC Instance Profile) for you to be selected as the 'EC2 Instance Profile'. In the past few months, I've found that that has changed and now you have to create that role manually through the IAM console. The instructions to do this are very clear and found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html. I've followed those instructions successfully in the past.
However, today when I'm trying the same thing, the role that I create does not seem to actually get wrapped as an EC2 Instance Profile. I can create the role and all the permissions and the JSON policy for the 'Trusted entities' looks exactly the same as all my other AWS accounts, however the role does not appear in the EB wizard as an option. Notably, the 'Summary' section or the created role is missing the 'Instance profile ARN'.
Here's a screengrab of the created role, showing the 'Trusted entities' tab:

Either I'm missing something really obvious, or whatever was associating IAM Roles with EC2 Instance Profiles in AWS has broken.

Did you check this detailed answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605 ? It has mentioned step-by-step instruction on how to setup the EC2 instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

Hi @ArpitJain thanks for the comment. Yes, I've followed those instructions exactly (as I've done many times, successfully, in the recent past). The difference this time is that the Instance Profile for this role is not generated.

I never got a clear answer from anyone as to why the instance profile was not getting generated in this AWS account. However, I did manage to overcome this problem by creating the instance profile via the AWS CLI (there's no facility to manage instance profiles through the console). If anyone can explain that to me, I'll be sure to mark your answer as correct.
There's two commands to use, one to create an instance profile:
aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name eb-instance-profile

And then another to wrap this instance profile around the role (that I'd already created):
aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --instance-profile-name eb-instance-profile --role-name ec-beanstalk-instance-role

Along the way I discovered CloudShell for the first time, which saves me fussing around with environment variables.
